# opencv-python installation issue using pip

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, importerror, python-venv

I am trying to install `opencv-python` inside a python venv using pip in one server env (ubuntu 22.04, python version 3.10.6). When i try to import like `import cv2` I am facing the below error

```
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

In one of the SO Answers, suggested that `opencv-python-headless` will work. I tried and it worked in my machine.

Now I also want  to install `rapid_latex_ocr` where `open-cv` is one of the dependency which automatically added when i install rapid_latex_ocras `pip install rapid_latex_ocr`.

My venv contains both `opencv-python-headless and opencv-python`, again the **ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory** problem repeated when i `import cv2`

What should i do in this situation ?
Kindly help.

Comment: "install pdfplumber where open-cv is one of the dependency" -- is it, really? When i go through the dependency chain of `pdfplumber 0.10.3` I don't see OpenCV anywhere. Where do you see that? What concrete package causes causes it to be pulled in in your environment?

Comment: @DanMašek sorry the issue from **rapid_latex_ocr** not from **pdfplumber**. I changed the question, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Right. Looks like that one doesn't use anything which would require a GUI, so it should work with the headless variant as well. Clone the source code from [github](https://github.com/RapidAI/RapidLaTeXOCR), edit `requirements.txt` to require `opencv-python-headless` instead of `opencv-python`, install the package from the local source code.

Comment: execute: sudo apt install -y libgl1-mesa-dev

Comment: "both" means the packages will conflict

Comment: based on @eyllanesc comment, i installed **opencv-python** & able to *import cv2* without any error.